# Var init in do-catch

Tags: swift, swift2

Following code:

```
// Setup components
do {
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let deviceInput   = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
    let output        = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    let session       = AVCaptureSession()
} catch {
    return false
}
```

After this you can't access the initialized variables. The error is "Use of unresolved identifier" if I want to access e.g. `deviceInput`. But why? Either `AVCaptureDeviceInput()` crashes and the catch-Block returns or all is right and the variables are successfully initialized. What's the best solution to solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vacawama's answer is perfectly correct, but just for educational purposes, here's a simplified version. You don't need anything but the initialization of `deviceInput` to happen inside a `do` block:

```
func test() {
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let deviceInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput
    do { deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) } catch {return}
    let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    let session  = AVCaptureSession()
    // ... other stuff here
    print("got to here")
}
```

If the `try` fails, "got to here" never prints; we have exited the function in good order.

Still another approach might be to let your surrounding function throw and just go for it, with no `do...catch` at all:

```
func test() throws {
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
    let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    // ... other stuff here
    print("got to here")
}
```

This moves the onus of error-checking onto the caller of `test()`.

Comment: Good stuff especially the second example.

Comment: We seem to have a fun new toy to play with. :)

Answer (score 5):

The `do` block defines a new scope.  If you declare the variables with `let` or `var` inside of the `do {}`, then they are only accessible within that block.  If you want to use them after the `do {}`, then declare them before the `do` statement.  Note, that you don't have to give them initial values, even if they are declared with `let` because you will only be setting them once before using them:

```
func foo() -> Bool {
    // Setup components
    let deviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
    let captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice
    let output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput
    let session: AVCaptureSession

    do {
        captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        deviceInput   = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        output        = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        session       = AVCaptureSession()
    } catch {
        return false
    }

    // Do something to demo that the variables are accessible
    print(deviceInput.description)
    print(output.description)
    print(session.description)

    return false
}
```